# Syntax error when I try to contact all elements

Tags: scala

I wish to contact all elements in the array into an List, but there is syntax error "missing argument list for method apply in object List Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. "

```
val pairs = Array((2, 5, 2), (5, 3, 1), (3, 1, 3))
pairs.foldLeft(List[Int]){(acc, a)=>acc:::a.toList()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `List[Int]()` instead of just `List[Int]`

`List[Int]` is only a type while `List[Int]()` will call the apply method of `List[Int]` thus creating and empty list.

This code still won't work as there is no `toList` method for tuples. One way to do it is simply to create a list with the elements of the tuple: `List(a._1, a._2, a._3)`

Comment: And lastly, `toList` doesn't take an argument list, so `toList()` will first convert to a list, and then try to apply `()` to it (in other words, it is equivalent to `toList.apply()`), i.e. getting the "none-th" element, which makes no sense. (`List.apply` takes at least one argument.)